# Click or mouseup event for div in Google Translate

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a JavaScript bookmarklet to make a shortcut for [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/). For example, typing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>\</kbd> will [clear the TextArea](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29920876/google%20Translate/googleTranslateShortcut.html). And now I want to add a shortcut that, when typing <kbd>]</kbd>, will swap the translate language; and <kbd>\</kbd> will pronounce the text.

Each are wrapped in `div#gt-lang-swap` and `div#gt-src-listen`, but I can't fire those events in the console.

I tried:

```
document.getElementById("gt-lang-swap").click()
```

But nothing happens. This didn't work either:

```
e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents")
e.initMouseEvent("mouseup", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false, 1, null)
document.getElementById('gt-src-listen').dispatchEvent(e)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I was trying to do exactly this. Did you end up getting your extension to work? It's so frustrating that I can't find shortcuts like this for google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `onclick` instead of just `click`?

```
document.getElementById("gt-lang-swap").onclick=function(){

   console.log('clicked it');

   //Other stuff that should happen...
}
```

Alternatively, try creating a function to fire off events (this function is taken from [here](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly))

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
       // dispatch for IE
       var evt = document.createEventObject();
       return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
       // dispatch for firefox + others
       var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
       evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
       return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

followed by:

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<script>
   obj = document.getElementById("test");
   Event.observe(obj,'change',function(){alert('hi');});
   fireEvent(obj,'change');
</script>
```

should do the trick...

N.B.: As mentioned in the comments and the linked article, this answer has a prerequisite of the [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library...
As such it may not be (after discussion) the ideal answer to this problem.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for more

Comment: well I'm not trying to add event handler on it, but try to fire the event

Comment: Does this help: `document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")` it comes from this article on creating test events: http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly If so, I can add it to this answer.

Comment: What doesn't work, there are many ideas in the article... What did you try? I'll update my answer with what I think is what you need...

Comment: thanks but I try every methods in that article...
maybe you can try it on google translate website and see if there is any method that can trigger the events...
it's kind of wired....

Comment: In google Chrome 23, it says "Object function Event() { [native code] } has no method 'observe'"

Comment: what I'm trying to do as simple as use console to fire the swap language events....  
but I was failed after four hours trying...

Comment: Sorry, That method is part of the library "prototype" mentioned in the article, I should have specified in the answer. But I think importing a whole library is overkill for your problem... I would suggest going with attaching a listener in the short term. :(

Comment: Funny, this was just posted on HTML5Rocks and is quite relevant to the discussion above... http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to trigger a click event on that button, but I figured you don't need to, since you can just modify the URL and the UI will update accordingly:

```
var components = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('/');
window.location = '#' + components[1] + '/' + components[0] + '/' + components[2];
document.getElementById('source').select(); // optionally focus user back into source field
```

so for example if the url is `#es/en/hola%20amigo`, this code swaps the first two language keys around so it becomes `#en/es/hola%20amigo`.

I suppose you could even use `document.getElementById('result_box')` to grab the translated text and put that into the source field!

If you update your extension please let me know, I would love to use it.

Edit: just realised this question is nearly two years old. Hopefully someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but:
If you want to place a listener to any element js has to use  [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) example:

```
const whereverElement = document.getElement[wherever selector you prefer]
whereverElement.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    // your code after the event happened here
}
```

You can bind the element to wherever event you want to listen to: ['change', 'click', 'mouseup', 'mousedown'], just look at for what you need.